# javascript HTMLCollection access

Tags: javascript, children, htmlcollection

I made a website and need to impelment javascript. I would like to get the child nodes from my HTML menu.

Here is a part of my HTML structure:

```
    <ul class="menu">
       <div class="moduletable_menu">
          <ul class="nav menu nav-pills">
             <li class="item-101">
             <li class="item-108 current active deeper parent">
             <li class="item-127">
             <li class="item-113 deeper parent">
             <li class="item-124">
             <li class="item-116 deeper parent">
          </ul>
       </div>
    </ul>
```

So, I would like to get the "active" element.
I made the following code:

```
    function getmenuItem(){
   var SelectedItem = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
   console.log(SelectedItem);
   console.log(SelectedItem.length);
    }
```

Here comes the problem:

I displayed the console via Firebug and it showed me

```
HTMLCollection[]
0
```

Then I tried to access the Collection with `SelectedElement[0]` but I got "undefined".

Please show me how to get the children of the active element.

Comment: You dont have 'active' class anywhere.

Comment: I thought with active I got the <li class="item-108 current active deeper parent"> because there is the active statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element can only be found after the HTML page has been constructed. If your piece of code is standalone in a `<script>` in the document `<head>`, there is no element of class `"active"` yet.

Place your code in `windows.onload`, which is called after the page has been loaded and its elements created:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var SelectedItem = document.getElementsByClassName("active");

    console.log(SelectedItem);
    console.log(SelectedItem.length);
}
```

Then your collection should have a length of 1 and you can access the first element with `[0]`. The code will also work when evoked from event handlers like `onclick`, which will only fire if the document is there already. (Because otherwise there wouödn't be any button to click.)